# Sort the order of dataframe columns based on the values in the bottom row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I tried this but it does not work:

```
df5[[c for c in sorted(list(df5.columns), key=df5.iloc[-1].get, reverse=True)]]
```

Comment: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please also see how to make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case, I think I have understood what you were looking for based on your example code and hopefully I answered it. I've tried to clarify the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [ 4, 5, 2], 'c': [2, 4, 5]})
print(df)

df = df[[x for _, x in sorted(zip(df.iloc[-1], df.columns), reverse=True)]]
print(df)
```

Starting DataFrame:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  4  2
1  2  5  4
2  3  2  5
```

Columns sorted by the values in the bottom row, in descending order:

```
  c  a  b
0  2  1  4
1  4  2  5
2  5  3  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('your_data_file')
sort_column = data.sort_values('name_of_column',ascending=False)
print(sort_column)
```